# I have already installed react and create-react-app globally. But when i try to start a new react app it starts installing react again

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, ubuntu-18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I have isntalled react-dom as well. Why do I have to reinstall all these again?

Answer (score 3):

Because React is a dependency of your **project**, not in your **environment**.

When your site is a live, you can't tell the clients: If you're looking for the React part, don't worry, it's on my machine.. It has to bundled with the rest of your code.

Also, if you have 2 projects with different React's version how it should be managed?

Unlike create-react-app which is used only to **generate** the project. Once the project been created, it's not connected to the tool (create-react-app) in any way.

Think of it like a car. No one cares if the car made in one country or another (create-react-app / manually / forked from OpenSource) as long as it has engine (React).

Comment: So i need to install react everytime i create a new app? Moreover the size of directory is 172 mb. Isn't it too large for a simple app?

Comment: Actually I created an app once and now when I need another one, I just duplicate the folder..

Comment: Yes, you need to install it with every project that uses it.  @MoshFeu's solution of copying and pasting the folder (raayon muzar chaver), is functionally the same.  As far as the size of node_modules, yes, there are many jokes about that folder being giant.  Check out this article: [The node_modules problem](https://dev.to/leoat12/the-nodemodules-problem-29dc).  But it doesn't mean the end project will be that large, just the development resources.  172 does sound big.  What else is in there?  CRA creates a project that is 172MG heavy?